# CSS Multi-Level Accordion Menu -- Pointer & Icon

Tags: javascript, css, menu, accordion, multi-level

https://codyhouse.co/demo/multi-level-accordion-menu/index.html

I used the above example to build my large, multi-level accordion menu for a mobile website.

Everything went well but when I reduced the left margins of the menu items, a ">" pointer, that turns 90% when open, and an icon of a folder got crammed over the text of the menu items.

I want to be able to reduce the left margins of the pointers and delete the folder icon.

[Page after updating with problem: superimposed pointer and icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spwEA.jpg)

[Page before changing the margins and colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldf89.jpg)

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: The page is available here:
https://phoenicia.org/menu/fly.html

Comment: If you put your faulty example in a snippet, jsfiddle or equivalent; it would make it much easier for you to find help.

Comment: Thanks, izulito,
Regrets, the code is too long.  I'll try to see if I can attach it.

Comment: One CSS file:
https://phoenicia.org/menu/css/style.css

Comment: Second CSS file: https://phoenicia.org/menu/css/reset.css

Comment: JQuery:
https://phoenicia.org/menu/js/jquery-2.1.4.js

Comment: JS:
https://phoenicia.org/menu/js/main.js

Comment: JS:
https://phoenicia.org/menu/js/modernizr.js

Comment: Hey Cyril. Welcome to StackOverflow! You should try and make sure your question has all of the information/code/images inside the question and avoid using external links. Also make sure to ask a specific question in the title.

Comment: zachzum, I tried to post the details right here but the files are too large and do not fit.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Here's a starting point. I'm not going to complete the code for you. You should be able to figure out the rest from here. You can right click, inspect element, then play around with the CSS instead of going back and forth between the page and your code (this will not save so remember to copy it over to your code).

Add `background: none` to the following:

Remove Menu folder:

```
.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
    background-position: -32px 0;
    background: none;
}
```

Remove Home folder:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)
style.css:215
.cd-accordion-menu ul label::after, .cd-accordion-menu ul a::after {
    /* left: 65px; */
    background: none;
}
```

Remove label folders:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)
style.css:215
.cd-accordion-menu ul label::after, .cd-accordion-menu ul a::after {
    /* left: 65px; */
    background: none;
}
```

Remove left positioning for label icons:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)
style.css:211
.cd-accordion-menu ul label::before {
    left: 65px;
}
```

You reduce the "margin" by removing `padding-left` from the following CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)
style.css:206
.cd-accordion-menu ul label, .cd-accordion-menu ul a {
    padding-left: 60px;
}
```

Reduce padding from 60 to 40 in the following CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)
style.css:208
.cd-accordion-menu ul label, .cd-accordion-menu ul a {
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Here's how it looks:

[image]

Comment: This looks good but the ">" pointers have disappeared.  I want to keep them to the left of the menu items.

Comment: The page in your comments: phoenicia.org/menu/fly.html doesn't have the pointers.

Comment: Of course, the pointers and icons are there in fly.html.

If you make the window 480 px, you will see them.

Comment: I updated my code. This should give you a starting point. It doesn't solve the sub menus, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Anthony.  Your assistance is most appreciated.  I got the arrows to the left, as you did, but their spacing from the text is less than yours. 

It is great to communicate with a friendly knowledgeable programmer who does not arrogantly treat those who do not know as much as he does.

Answer (score 0):

The chevron and folder are in the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements respectively. They are absolutely positioned. The inner component before had enough padding that the body text started after the icons. You removed the left padding so that was no longer the case. Since they aren't in document flow the will not be affected by a change in padding.

In my opinion, you should build components like this your self since any level of customization will require almost as much work digging into someone else code, without any guaranty that it's well written.

If you want to just get rid of the icons set

```
   .cd-accordion-menu label::before, 
   .cd-accordion-menu label::after {
      content: none;
   }
```

It looks like the css you're using is responsive so make sure to test on different screen sizes or remove the media queries. It probably will look fine on your screen but not on everyone's.

Also fyi padding vs margin aren't synonyms make sure to use the one you mean. If you don't know you should read up on the [box-model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)